# My Iranian passport has expired. Can I still leave Australia?

Tags: visa, residency

I'm an Iranian citizen and a permanent resident of Australia and have been living here for nearly 3 years. I will be eligible for citizenship in a year. My Iranian passport expired a month ago and I plan to travel to Iran in a couple of months. Will I be allowed to exit the country?

Comment: Can you not get a new passport?  http://en.canberra.mfa.ir/

Comment: Yes I can but their site says it takes 6 weeks at least and they're not exactly prompt with these things and I'm traveling on May 17.

Answer (score 1):

With no current passport, airlines may refuse to board you. I would suggest you get a new passport from the Iranian embassy in Canberra (but I don't know for certain they can issue one to you).

Comment: Please read my reply to the previous comment. Any further recommendations?

Comment: Maybe contact the airline and ask if you will be allowed to board. Unless your flight is direct, also check that you will be able to transfer in the connecting airport. Lastly, figure out how you will get back to Australia.

Comment: The last part (going back to Australia) is more critical. I would be reasonable sure that you can get to Iran somehow with an expired Iranian passport, but not to Australia, even if you are a three year resident. The airline in Iran will give you trouble when you try boarding to Australia.